# Should I free the handle returned from GCHandle::FromIntPtr?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am using GCHandle::FromIntPtr to convert unmanaged structure pointer to  managed object reference follow an example in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.fromintptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Below is my code snippet:

```
GCHandle gch = GCHandle::FromIntPtr(IntPtr(someNativePtr));
MyManagedClass^ obj = static_cast<MyManagedClass^>(gch.Target);
```

My question is should I free gch?

**UPDATE:**
  There's a huge problem in this question just as Medinoc mentioned in his comment: GCHandle::FromIntPtr can **not** accept an IntPtr which points to an unmanaged object!!! So the question is completely pointless.

Comment: @Medinoc, thx, where can I find the document you just mentioned?

Comment: @Medinoc,I don't think the msdn example really mean we can only use FromIntPtr with intptr returned by ToIntPtr.

Comment: The MSDN doc doesn't say you can create a GCHandle out of thin air from a random IntPtr that doesn't even point to a managed object. It says you can convert a GCHandle into an IntPtr and back into a GCHandle for the purpose of passing it as context through unmanaged functions (that by definition only accept pointers or intptr_t-like types).

Comment: @Medinoc, MSDN explains its sole parameter as "An IntPtr handle to a managed object to create a GCHandle object from." So I take it as the function can accept any IntPtr as long as it points to a managed object. And I can not find any information that it can only accept IntPtr which is converted from GCHandle.FYI: I am newbie to c++

Comment: You said it yourself: "An IntPtr **handle** to a managed object". IIRC you can't directly cast a `SomeClass^` managed handle into an IntPtr, which leaves the GCHandle class as the only means of creating one.

Comment: @Medinoc, you really punch me in the face.Indeed, I am wrong, you're correct. If you'd like turn the comment to a reply, I'd be glad to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSDN doc doesn't say you can create a GCHandle out of thin air from a random `IntPtr` that doesn't even point to a managed object. It says you can convert a `GCHandle` into an `IntPtr` and back into a `GCHandle` for the purpose of passing it as context through unmanaged functions (that by definition only accept pointers or `intptr_t`-like types)

As a consequence, the only kind of `IntPtr` you're supposed to pass to `GCHandle::FromIntPtr()` is one that was returned by `GCHandle::ToIntPtr()`.

Answer (score 3):

FromIntPtr method returns a new GCHandle (value-type) struct created from a handle to a managed object, while Alloc method Allocates a handle for the specified object.

So you need to call Free() on the GCHandle struct only if you got it by a call to Alloc() not FromIntPtr()

Reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.alloc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I am not familiar with c++ or c++/cli, but it seems your answer is correct. Although GCHandle is unmanaged type, but we don't explicitly alloc it, so we have no responsibility to release it. Is this explaination right?

Comment: The documentation is definitely light on detail here. I'd suggest reading this article, [The Truth About GCHandles](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clyon/2005/03/18/the-truth-about-gchandles/), for a bit more explanation of what's going on. tl;dr: it appears that @Rami is correct.